# What query protocol does Battlefield 2 use?

Tags: protocols

I have been searching for this all over the internet, [this site](http://wiki.hlsw.net/index.php/GameServer_protocols) claims that Battlefield 2 uses the GameSpy 2 protocol, I have tried this protocol, but it does not respond. I have also been working on the GameSpy 3 protocol, but that one is a lot harder.
I would like to know which one it uses so I know whether I am using the wrong protocol, or have an error in my code.

Comment: Can your code talk correrctly to any other GameSpy 2 protocol programs? That may point you towards the probable point of failure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Battlefield 2 uses the Gamespy 3 protocol.

Source: [GameQ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gameq/) library

From the GameQ config file:

```
[bf2]
name = "Battlefield 2"
port = 29900
prot = "gamespy3"
pack = "bf2"
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) This saves me a lot of senseless work.